# Temperature Difficulties of a Fluctuating Orbital Distance

Tags: science-based, earth-like, orbital-mechanics, solar-system, temperature

I'm presently working on a setting that involves a planet orbiting a secondary star, a Red Dwarf, (let's call her Star B) which in turn orbits a G/K class star (Star A). I intend for this planet to be habitable by humans, as well as some indigenous aquatic lifeforms, so the purpose is to balance orbits so that the planet is able to be warmed by both Star A and B, but not fried by either. Star B will need an orbit greater than 1 AU, so that Star A will not completely fry our planet, but some of the heat our planet receives must be from Star A (since we're dealing with a Red Dwarf as the alternative), so it can't be too far.

Now I present the problem. Since our planet will be orbiting Star B, the distance between the planet and Star A will constantly be shifting. [This website](http://www.atlasoftheuniverse.com/startype.html) suggests that a planet orbiting a Red Dwarf should be anywhere from .28 to .03 AU away from the said star, which means that every planetary orbit will increase and decrease the distance between the planet and Star A by .56-.06 AU (doubled, as the orbital distance is the radius). If you are able, an answer considering both of the possible extremes would most likely be the most informative (so that the reader could then infer the range in between the extremes). What sort of problems would this orbital deficit present? Would a dense atmosphere aide in the reparations of these problems?

I am not necessarily concerned with the heat of Star B, but rather how these differences in distance between Star A and the planet will affect the planet's temperature, and general habitability. Would every orbit of the planet cause seasons of sorts, much like Fox-Chan suggested, or would it barely impact the temperature of the planet?

PS - I have already planned for this planet to have a dense atmosphere and robust magnetosphere, due to its proximity to Star B, but I don't know if this would affect the problem I have presented at all.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding Gladiens!

Comment: Thank you sir! This community looks like a very exciting and informative opportunity to take part in in.

Comment: Also related: [Orbiting one star in a binary system: what are the effects of the second star on the planet?](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/25166/29), [How can I safely brighten my secondary star?](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/25203/29), [How much does my secondary star heat the planet orbiting my primary star?](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/32193/29), and probably some others.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I'm rather content with the information that I have come across on my own (I am now, however, I wasn't at the time of my questioning)- is there a reason for it to be closed, even with an accepted answer?

Comment: @Gladiens The accepted answer isn't particularly thorough. Answer acceptance doesn't change whether a question asks about the same thing as an existing question. If you feel this isn't a duplicate of the proposed duplicate, you should [edit] your question to highlight the differences. See [Why are some questions marked as duplicate?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates) for some further discussion on this. If you have learned enough to answer this, you may also [answer your own question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) to help others in the future.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling The sad thing is that I've learned enough on my own to simply abandon this scenario altogether, and change it to something else, so I have no exact answer. I will do my very best to differentiate it from the other questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly, It would depend on the fluctuations, otherwise, it would simply be like seasons, if it was closer the fluctuations would be more warm rather than hot and vice versa. If this wasn't the answer you were looking for try narrowing your topic a little bit.

Comment: and yes a dense atmosphere would help keep the red star's temperature out of it

Comment: Thank you greatly! I will try to add more information, as to narrow down the question. I appreciate your input- and hope to receive more in the future!

Comment: yup! no problem, Im here to help with any other questions you may have